# KeyPressed not working in each program

Tags: java

I transferred a few programs from a computer at my school(a mac) at school to my home pc. Once on my computer, I noticed the keys now do not work in each program. I've spent hours try to figure out why KeyPressed isn't working. Both computers used Eclipse

Is it because of different Java version or because of a different OS?
Thank you!

example of code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Skeleton extends JApplet implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {

    Random generator = new Random();
    boolean GameRunning = true, PlayAgain = true;
    int width, height;
    int score = 0;
    Image offscreenImage;

    int XX;
    int XY;
    Image Cart;
    Image candy[];
    int candyX[];
    int candyY[];
    boolean up = false, down = false, left = false, right = false;
    boolean candyRemaining[];
    Graphics offscr;
    Random r;
    Thread t;
    boolean inBounds = true;
    boolean onScreen = true;
    Image Title;
    boolean hasStarted = false;

    public Skeleton() {
        r = new Random();
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void init() {
        XX = 0;
        XY = 0;
        candy = new Image[3];
        candyRemaining = new boolean[3];
        candyY = new int[3];
        candyX = new int[3];
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;
        Title = getImage(getCodeBase(), "BKG.png");
        offscreenImage = createImage(width, height);
//      offscr = offscreenImage.getGraphics();
        Cart = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Untitled-1.png");
        candy[0] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "candy1.png");
        candy[1] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "candy2.png");
        candy[2] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "candy3.png");
        candyRemaining[0] = true;
        candyRemaining[1] = true;
        candyRemaining[2] = true;
        candyX[0] = 100;
        candyX[1] = 300;
        candyX[2] = 400;
        candyY[0] = 425;
        candyY[1] = 0;
        candyY[2] = 210;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        Random generator = new Random();
        if (hasStarted) {
            if (inBounds) {
                g.drawImage(Cart, XX, XY, this);
                this.Candy(g);
                if (left) {
                    XX -= 5;
                    if (XX < 0) {
                        XX += 5;
                    }
                }
                if (right) {
                    XX += 5;
                    if (XX > 500) {
                        XX -= 5;
                    }
                }
                if (down) {
                    XY += 5;
                    if (XX > 500) {
                        XY -= 5;
                    }
                }
                if (up) {
                    XY -= 5;
                    if (XY < 0) {
                        XY += 5;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                GameRunning = false;
            }
        } else {
            g.drawImage(Title, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    public void Candy(Graphics g) {
        for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
            if (candyRemaining[count]) {
                g.drawImage(candy[count], candyX[count], candyY[count], this);
                if (candyX[count] < XX + 50 && candyX[count] + 50 > XX) {
                    if (candyY[count] < XY + 50 && candyY[count] + 50 > XY) {
                        System.out.println(count);
                        candyRemaining[count] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (PlayAgain == true) {
            while (GameRunning == true) {
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                };
            }
            if (GameRunning == false) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) {
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent ev) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
        if (!hasStarted) {
            hasStarted = true;
        }
        if (GameRunning == false) {
            if (ev.getX() > 0 && ev.getX() < 1000 && ev.getY() > 0 && ev.getY() < 1000) {
                GameRunning = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        onScreen = true;
        inBounds = true;
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ev) {
        onScreen = false;
        inBounds = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == e.VK_A) {
            left = true;
        }
        if (key == e.VK_D) {
            right = true;
        }
        if (key == e.VK_S) {
            down = true;
        }
        if (key == e.VK_W) {
            up = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Released");
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == e.VK_A) {
            left = false;
        }
        if (key == e.VK_D) {
            right = false;
        }
        if (key == e.VK_S) {
            down = false;
        }
        if (key == e.VK_W) {
            up = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's definitely not because of different OS versions. Java runs on all computers

Comment: It's supposed to... But that doesn't mean AWT is bug-free.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Given the amount of code that is running world wide, and the age of the AWT API, it's unlikely to be bug.  It's more likely to a misuse or misunderstanding of the API

Comment: I've made a Swing app that didn't work under Compiz... I've seen javac crash... For sure, problems with big old libraries are usually your own fault. Sometimes they're not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the object `e` for your keycodes, use the `static` `KeyEvent` class. In addition your code will look prettier if you use a `switch` statement instead of `if` statements:

```
switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_A: // here's the change
            left = true;
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing the keypressed or released you are using the current KeyEvent class's object.
As everytime the key is pressed the new KeyEvent object is created and for keypressed you are checking with the current object which doesn't hold the keyvalue, it just hold's that which key was pressed.
So to check refer to the static variables of the KeyEvent Class.

```
   switch(e.getKeyCode){
      case: KeyEvent.VK_A;
        Left =false;
      break;
      case: KeyEvent.VK_D;
        right=false;
      break;
      .
      .
      .
      .
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListener` is nutritiously fickle about focus.  A `KeyListener` can only be notified of key events when the component is focusable and has focus

The short answer would be to use

```
setFocusable(true);
requestFocusInWindow();
```

at the end of the `init` method

The more appropriate answer would be to use [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which provides you with the ability to control the level of focus required in order to generate key events

As a side note, it would be more appropriate to use something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` and use it as the primary gaming component instead of the `JApplet`, which isn't double buffered and can flash when it's updated...

You should also move you gaming logic out of your paint method and probably into you main gaming loop (or called from your gaming loop).  A paint cycle could be called at any time, many times outside of your control, which could effect your output.

I also doubt you need 500fps, `Thread.sleep(40);` or even `Thread.sleep(16);` will probably give you far more stable results